# Can you use Generic Action<> or Func<> parameters with the where clause?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I am not sure if I am missing something or just not understanding the way in which the complier works... Basically I want to be able to pass an action with a constrained parameter without having to recast it. Take the below code with the cast which works:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<ICommand>> _dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ICommand>>();

    public void Register<TCommand>(Action<TCommand> action) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        _dictionary.Add(typeof(TCommand), x => action((TCommand)x));
    }
```

The following throws an error and says that a parameter of TCommand can't be passed as an ICommand

```
    public void Register<TCommand>(Action<TCommand> action) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        _dictionary.Add(typeof(TCommand), action);
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it that the **where** constraint is only understood by the method signature and the rest of the code ignores this directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first generic argument to `Action` is *contravariant* not *covariant*.  `Action<ICommand>` is not a sub-type of `Action<SomeCommand>`.  In fact, it's the other way around.  `Action<SomeCommand>` *is a sub type of* `Action<ICommand>`!

Right now you have an action that can take only a `SomeCommand`.  If you could cast it to `Action<ICommand>` then someone could pass in an `EvilCommand`, but an `EvilCommand` is not a type of `SomeCommand`.  On the other hand, if you've written a method that can accept any type of `ICommand`, then obviously you could pretend that it was a method that only accepts `SomeCommand` objects, because you *know* all of them will implement `ICommand`.

Your first solution works because you're introducing the explicit cast of the parameter.  You're *creating a new method*, one that performs the specific type check needed.  In addition to working, it is also the correct design in this specific case; it's one of those rare situations where *you* know that the object is in fact a `TCommand` instance, not just an `ICommand`, but the compiler can't prove it, and there aren't any really good ways of re-designing the application such that it could statically verify that.